# Rewriting multiple path components in a URL

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite

I am developing the CRM like WordPress i am stuck in to generate custom URL like

> www.website.com/category/some_text_here/

How in PHP I will fetch the `category` and `some_text_here` in the page so that I can fetch content from the database from the page.

Here i have tried something like :

```
<?php
 if (isset($_GET['slug'])) {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE slug = ? LIMIT 1";
      $smt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $smt->execute(array($_GET['slug']));
      $row = $smt->fetchObject();
        // do something with the matching record here...
      }
  else {
       // display home page
   }
```

And .htaccess page :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?slug=$1
```

But the problem what I am facing is whenever i am loading this page I am getting index.php`[URL : localhost/some_text_here/]` and I am not able to fetch category too.
What will be the best way to accomplish this task. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need multiple capture groups.  Right now, you only have the one.

Comment: Can you help me how can I get category and some_text_here in the page?

Comment: _“I am getting index.php`[URL : localhost/some_text_here/]`”_ - what, where would the `localhost` part come from? (Are you even talking about the value of the slug parameter here, or something else?) Your problem description is vague and imprecise, please edit it to be more clear on what is actually happening.